# How to fix NotFoundHttpException laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Hi all I am a new of laravel 5.1,I just start learning laravel. I have problame in laravel I can not find the way to correct it I try to search but I still can not.I want to update form, but when I click button update its show error

```
NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php line 46: No query results for model [App\Course].

ModelNotFoundException in Builder.php line 129: No query results for model [App\Course].
```

And here is my code:
 CourseController.php

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        $data = Course::findOrFail($id);
        $data->update($input);

        return redirect('course');
    }
```

and my model Course.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;



class Course extends Model
{
    protected $table = "course";
    protected $primaryKey = "course_id";

    protected $fillable=[
    'course_title',
    'course_code',
    'course_credite'
    ];
}
```

And here is my view edite.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    {!! Form::open(array('route'=>['course.update','$course->course_id'],'class'=>'jack','method'=>'PUT')) !!}

    {!! Form::label('Course_title','Course Title',array('class'=>'aswe')) !!}
    {!! Form::text('course_title', $value=$course->course_title, $att = array('class'=>'blu','id'=>'single','required')) !!}

    {!! Form::label('Course_code','Code_title',array('class'=>'no')) !!}
    {!! Form::text('course_code',$value=$course->course_code,$att = array('class','blue','required')) !!}

    {!! Form::label('Course_creadit','creadit_title',array('class'=>'no')) !!}
    {!! Form::text('course_credite',$value=$course->course_credite,$att = array('class','blue','required')) !!}

    {!! Form::submit('submit',$att=array('class'=>'has')) !!}

    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my route

```
Route::resource('course','CourseController');
```

Comment: How are you attempting to access the update route; via a form submission, via a link, or just as part of an API call?

Comment: I want to update form

Comment: and see my update question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is how you're opening the form:

```
{!! Form::open(array('route'=>['course.update','$course->course_id'],'class'=>'jack','method'=>'PUT')) !!}
```

There are single-quotes around the parameter to the route, so it'd be looking to pass in the literal string "$course->course_id". To fix this, you can simply remove those quotes:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['course.update', $course->course_id], 'class' => 'jack', 'method' => 'PUT']) !!}
```

Comment: errorFatalErrorException in 1639b421229799a05179ba35ce56fc67 line 9: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ']'

Comment: Yeah, because I mixed up the closing `]` and `)`. I just edited my question to address that. Whoops!

Answer (score 0):

**Dirty way:**

you may replace `findOrFail()` with `find` only and just handle it programmatically with `if(!is_null($user))`

**Clean way:**

Create a new exception file to catch your exception or just have it here within your code like so:

```php
// Will return a ModelNotFoundException if no Course with that id
try
{
    $data = Course::findOrFail($id);
    $data->update($input);

    return redirect('course');
}
// catch(Exception $e) catch any exception
catch(ModelNotFoundException $e)
{
    dd(get_class_methods($e)); // lists all available methods for exception object
    dd($e);
    // you might do here
    session()->flash('message', ['danger', 'Oops no such course found !']);
    return redirect('course'); // please mind to change it later to use names route or perhabs action()
}
```

And in your course index view right the following HTML to render the error

```
@include('errors.alert',['type'=> Session::get('message.0'),'message' => Session::get('message.1') ])
```

and for sure create this partial view `errors/alert.blade.php`:

```html
<div class="alert alert-{{ $type }} alert-page alert-dark">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    {!! $message  !!}
</div>
```

Comment: I'm gonna leave it, it might help another one :smile: